# Missing VPN options in Windows 10 compared to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn

I notice that in Windows 8.1 there was the following options for what type of VPN you want to add.

[image: vpn options in windows 8.1]

But in Windows 10 they have all been replaced with the option Microsoft. Is there a way to add the previous options back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those VPN selections were not built in to Windows 8 / 8.1.

I used Windows 8 / 8.1 and commercial VPN tools. Juniper on Windows 8 / 8.1.

On Windows 10, I use now Sonic Wall VPN.

These are commercial VPN tools and Microsoft never licensed them for broad consumption by the public. We had to buy the VPN packages we needed / need now.

So to the extent the commercial packages were on your Windows 8.1 machine, they were installed by the Company that set up your machine.  Plain Windows 8.1 did not include these VPN tools.

Neither does Windows 10 include anything but the Microsoft VPN applications built in.  You can purchase the VPN applications you need in the Windows 10 version.

I added Sonic Wall and NCP for Juniper to my current Windows 10 machine.

Nothing is missing on your Windows 10 box.